# Find the Balanced index Position(s) in Array

Tags: java, arrays

The given Array arr and its size is **N**, find the balanced index position(s) **P** such that the sum of **0 to P-1** array elements is equal to the product of **P+1 to N-1**.

In the worst case time complexity is **O(n)**:
I have tried with the below code, its working, if Array does not contain zero.

```
/**
* 
*/
package com.array.balance.indexes;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
* @author Prasad
*
*/
public class FindBalancedIndexesInArray {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getIndexes(new int[] { 1, 2, 1, 3 }));
    System.out.println(getIndexes(new int[] { 1, 2, 1 }));
}

private static Set<Integer> getIndexes(final int[] arr) {
    final Set<Integer> indexes = new HashSet<>();
    int leftElementsSum = 0;
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
        // return Empty set
        return indexes;
    }
    if (arr.length == 1) {
        // If it is Only One Element, previous and next are equal..
        indexes.add(0);
        return indexes;
    }
    /**
     * If the Array doesn't have zero, elements, then Time Complexity is O(n).
     */

    int product = arr[0];
    /**
     * Calculate Product of the array elements
     */
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        product *= arr[i];
    }
    /**
     * Time Complexity O(n)
     */
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // Calculate Previous Elements sum
        leftElementsSum += arr[i - 1];
        // calculate Product
        product = product / arr[i];
        // Check Previous Sum and Next Multiplication is Equal..
        if (leftElementsSum == product) {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    /**
     * For the last element in the array, if the SUM of 0 to N-2 Elements are ZERO,
     * then include last Element Index.
     */
    if (leftElementsSum == 0) {
        indexes.add(arr.length - 1);
    }
    return indexes;
}
}
```

Output:
[2]
[1]

**Note:** Array can have Real Numbers.

Can anyone help me..! 
**Edit:**
If the array has zero element(s), this code is fails.

## **Edit 2:**

1. new int[] { 5, 0, -5, 4 } 
   Expected Output: [0,3]
2. new int[] { 5, 0, -5, 4, 0, 6, 4 }
   Expected Output: [0,3,6]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz **No**. That is not how time complexity works. If anything it is O(2n) which is O(n).

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz because those are two loops, each O(n), they dont *multiply*, they *add* to complexity. A third loop from 0...<arr.length will once again be O(n) and the algorithm will stay O(n) overall.

Comment: oh dear it's 2n not n^2, such a noob. thanks @luk2302

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz , as i understood that ,If one For  loop inside another for loop then the time complexity is O(n^2), correct me if i wrong.

Comment: You are correct, now back on track: what is the question?

Comment: If the array contains zero elements, then the**product of the elements becomes zero**, so i cant able to find balanced index positions.

Comment: I did using for loop inside another one, its works, but the time complexity is O(n^2), Here is the code [link](https://github.com/Prasad2472/core-programs/blob/master/src/com/array/balance/indexes/FindBalancedIndexes.java)